import issues using jupyter notebook python via VSCode (RESOLVED)
I am trying to run the following Code Snippet in a Jupyter Notebook (Python) via VSCode and I am getting the following error:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

Error:
{
    "name": "ModuleNotFoundError",
    "message": "No module named 'matplotlib'",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 3
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 from scipy.integrate import odeint

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'"

I checked the active Virtual environment and I am certain its the right one. Its the only one the ipykernel is even installed in and  I installed and uninstalled matplotlib multiple times.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as far as I can see, most similiar issues were resolved by switching to the right venv.
EDIT
Looks like the issue was caused by moving my venv into this project, which caused matplot to not install properly. Creating a new venv resolved the issue.

Don't put "RESOLVED" in your title. Accepting an answer shows a question is resolved. If your answer is helpful to other people then you should post it as an answer and accept it (or delete the question).

Thats fair, its what I wanted to do initially, but the guidelines state to edit my post when I resolve my issue

Where in the guidelines does it say that?

When there were no answers and I wanted to click on answer it showed up.

What exactly did it say? I'd be surprised if it said to edit your question as you have done.
